# Display 2 weeks in view calendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

Is there a way to display only 2 weeks using jquery full calendar?

Comment: You ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

please take a look at [jQuery UI Documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#min-max)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({minDate: -20, maxDate: '+1M +10D'});
});
</script>
```

Comment: I fear your not fully understanding his problem, he's refering to the jQuery plugin FullCalendar (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/), not the date picker.